# How to reflect changes in a filtered list

Tags: java, list, filter

I have a list of String, and I want to store a filtered version of this list inside another list, so that when the original list is updated, the filtered list is also updated.

For example:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> filteredStrings = strings.stream().filter(string -> string.startsWith("#")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`filteredStrings` isn't updated whenever an element is added to `strings`. Is there a way that `filteredStrings` can be updated whenever an element is added to `strings`? Or are there any similar alternatives I can employ to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filteredStrings` is a completely new object, so changes aren't made to both.

If you want reflecting changes, then you'll have to write your own class, most likely.

Start with extending `ArrayList<String>`, and override the `add` method to only accept strings that start with `#`

---

Another option, if you don't want just those strings in the list is to not override the `add` method, but add a `ArrayList<String> startsWithFilter(String filter)` method that will always return the list with the reflected changes of your custom list.

Comment: I don't want to exclude other elements, I just want to filter certain elements. So I could have a filtered list that contains elements that start with "#" for example, and also ones that start with a "!" perhaps.

Comment: So you want one list with all the strings, then later filter that list with any character, but also update the filtered list when you change the original? Sorry, not sure that's possible, since it's a completely new object. I've updated the answer with another solution